# Why does $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|\widehat{f(n)}|<\infty$ gives that the matching Fourier series uniformly converges?

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis

I'd really love to understand why does the fact that the series of the absolute Fourier coefficient converges ($\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}|\widehat{f(n)}|<\infty$) for a function $f$,  leads to the fact that the whole Fourier series, $\sum_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}\widehat{f(n)}e^{inx}$, uniformly converges.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We have $\sup_{x\in\mathbb R}|\widehat f(n)e^{inx}|=|\widehat f(n)|$ so by [Weierstrass M-test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test), the series $\sum_{n\in\mathbb Z}\widehat f(n)e^{inx}$ is normally convergent on the real line, hence uniformly convergent.